# Evaluate a chain of character as a function with arguments in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do something like this

```
add <- function(a, b){a+b}
multipleadd <- "add(add(1,3),add(add(6,5),add(5,7)))"
print(something(multipleadd)) # 27
```

How do I make that "something" so that I can use 'multipleadd' as an argument of another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea (ie unsafe) to evaluate arbitrate strings of text, but you can do it with `eval()` and `parse()`

```
print(eval(parse(text=multipleadd)))
# [1] 27
```

Comment: Well, thanks for a so quick and working answer.  
What would you recommend as a safe way of doing the same thing ? Or, in other terms, how to pass a recursive (or not) function with arguments to another function ?

Comment: The problem here isn't that the function is recursive; the problem is that you are trying to execute a string. How did you create such a string? Where is it coming from?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to use a string, I want to pass a function to another function. The function that get the other one as an argument would watch and time the execution of the one passed to it. Then it will send me notifications (growl or similar, twitter, speak). So if my executed function looks like "myFunction(data=mydata, method="mymethod", and so on)" I want the watcher to tell me that myFunction as finished.

Comment: You can pass functions as parameters to other functions. R is a functional language so functions are first class objects.

Comment: I have tried and I don't manage to... If I pass the multipleadd from my first example, it considers that I give it 27 (the result) and not `add(add(1,3),add(add(6,5),add(5,7))`

Comment: Well, `add(add(1,3),add(add(6,5),add(5,7))` is not a function `function() add(add(1,3),add(add(6,5),add(5,7))` is. If I define `f<-function() add(1,2)`, and `run<-function(x) x()` I can call `run(f)`